# Javascript DOM changes have no effect

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using an image map, I am trying to build a graphic that when you click on a "wing" it makes it look like a button and depresses it.

Image map is built, onclick is working, but nothing happens?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <map name="location-map" style="cursor:pointer;">
  <area id="spot_1" onClick="set_spot(this.id)" shape="poly" coords="66,78,122,38,194,15,186,106,174,112,160,118" />
 </map>
 <img src="PH.png" usemap="#location-map" id="spot_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:402px;height:302px;" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function set_spot(mouse_over_name) {
    document.getElementById(mouse_over_name).style.display="none";
  };
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to hide the image?

I have seen other solutions saying that the position of the JavaScript needs to be after the element.  I have tried the script in every location and the out come is always the same.  No change.  I've also tried changing the width to 0 px and changing the image src to ""!  I also had the images inside DIV's and tried hiding the DIV but again, nothing?

If I put an an alert:
`alert(document.getElementById(mouse_over_name).style.display)` before the change, I get a blank alert box, after I get "none."

What am I missing?

You can see the above code live here:
http://www.beaconfasteners.net/beacon_advantage/graph/test.html

**Edit:**
I have tried this in all major browsers.

Comment: You have two elements with the same ID (`spot_1`). IDs need to be unique. Most likely you're not hiding the right element.

Answer (score 0):

Robby Cornelissen was correct.  The reason that your img is not hiding is because the onclick uses the id of the area element and you're setting display: none on that, not the img element.  I'm not sure if there is a way to hide the contents of an area element, but you could potentially use this to find and hide the image element that shares the same id as the area that is clicked:

```
function set_spot(mouse_over_name) { 
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), function(el) {
       if (el.id === mouse_over_name) {
           el.style.display = 'none';
       };
    });
};
```

This will iterate through all of the images on the page, so I can't make any guarantees about the speed of such a solution.  You can preview it here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvg6h0py/2/)

Comment: Two elements with spot_1 for an id was the issue! Thanks to both replies!